# How to quantify number of waiting blocks on main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, multithreading, instruments

I've inherited some code that throws any operation it can onto the main UI thread. For instance, when a network operation returns, the completion blocks are automatically run on the main thread and the programmers mix UI code with network requests willy-nilly.

How can I quantify the load or stress on the main UI thread, so that I can prove to a manager that putting everything on the main thread is a bad practice? I am hoping for a programmatic way to get this datum, because I also want to log it.

Comment: This is incredibly amusing to me. If you want to show him how not multithreading is a bad idea, do a network call to a slow API and let him watch your application freeze.

Comment: Instruments can do that.  I'd start here.  https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/411/.  And, yeah, that sounds like a recipe for nasty contention issues.

Comment: @Mike We're talking about someone who has done firmware programming, but who literally thinks that O(1) is an Emoji. He thinks sluggishness is caused by the backend.

Comment: @bbum I was hoping for a programmatic way to get the total blocks on the main thread, because I also want to log that number.

Comment: @Mike The OP talks about network call backs. How can the speed of an API cause a freeze of the app?

Comment: @oopo So, you do not see any disadvantages, when using the app, but you want to prove that there are disadvantages and get problems to do so?

Comment: To your Q: The code to get the number of waiting blocks on the main thread is quite simple: `int numberOfWaitingBlocks = 0;`. A completion handler for a network call isn't waiting. It is triggered. The load and the "stress" equals 0.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Huh?  Pounding the main thread from callbacks most assuredly can cause hiccups in the UI's responsiveness.  The architecture OP describes is rife with risk of this.   In general, network callbacks should be handled on a background queue, then any UI updates are dispatched to the main thread once data processing is complete and appropriate set of updates have been coalesced into a single update operation.

Comment: Obviously the app does not suffer under this theoretical existing risk. Otherwise the OP doesn't need help to prove it. And if most of the work of the call back is updating the UI, making things more complex is a bad idea. However, I never said that there isn't the risk of UI blocking. I said that there is no block "waiting". The Q seems to assume that the number of "waiting" blocks may do any harm. I wanted to clarify that this is not true. And a low speed of the API is definitely no risk.